# month wise headcount of the subcontractor for period Jan 14 to Dec 14

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table SOW ,which has columns ASSOCIATE, SOW_START_DATE, SOW_END_DATE,in which i need to get the count of associate for a month for year 2014, for eg i have associate Minal whose sow_start_date is 1-01-2014 and sow_end_date is 1-04-2014 i want query where minal is available for Jan,Feb,march and April.
i have tried this query but result is minal is available only for Jan month instead f Jan,Feb,march,April.

```
select year([SOW Start Date]) as [year], month([SOW Start Date]) as   [months], Associate
from SOW
where month([SOW Start Date]) in (MONTH([SOW Start Date]), MONTH([SOW End Date]))
and month([SOW Start Date]) =2 and YEAR([SOW Start Date])=2014
group by year([SOW Start Date]), month([SOW Start Date]),Associate 
having count(*) >= 1
order by month([SOW Start Date])
```

Comment: Why in your query you are filtering only for Feb records i.e by setting month([SOW Start Date]) =2 . Also Please type the sample exact o/p you are expecting by giving a sample records in DB and Sample O/p you are expecting as a result. Then it will help people to answer your query qucikly

Comment: What do you need? Count of months where Mimal is available or the actual list of months? A sample input & expected output data would be most helpful.

Comment: I want to have monthly count of employess.

Comment: @TomT , I need the month wise count of employees who has respective Start_date and End_date, My query returns only the count of employee according to start_date ,but i want month wise count of employees from start_date & end_date. and i have a table SOW.

Comment: @TomT Following is the SOW Table:                                                              Associate         SOW_Start_Date      SOW_End_Date
Abhishek          09-07-2013           07-10-2013
Abhishek          17-01-2015         13-03-2015
Tejaswini           03-12-2014         02-03-2015    
Tejaswini                 03-12-2014       02-03-2015
Mohini               18-12-2014     16-06-2015
Mohini              18-12-2014    16-06-2015
Anushree         15-12-2014   15-06-2015

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to list count of employees per month. The problem is that you need to join your sow table to some list of months. I guess you don't have one so you need to manufacture it. The you need to join your sow table to the list of months based on start/end dates. This way you will get a month-employee pair if the employee worked in that month. Finally you group by month and count employees:

```
-- identify the date range
declare @min date, @max date
select @min=min(sow_start_date), @max=max(sow_end_date) from sow

-- we will identify the month by its first day
declare @start date
select @start=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @min), 0)

-- generate all months in the min-max range
; with months as
(
  select @start as d

  union all

  select dateadd(mm, 1, d) as d from months where d < @max
)
-- move start dates to 1st day of month so the comparisson works
, sow2 as
(
  select associate, sow_end_date,
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, sow_start_date), 0) as sow_start_date
  from sow
)
-- link employees to months
, employee_month as
(
  select d, Associate from sow2 inner join months 
    on d >= sow_start_date and d < sow_end_date
)
-- count employees per month
select d, count(Associate) a from employee_month group by d
```

Check out the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52c94b/3/0

Comment: Thanks allot ,but i need to show all data of an employee. Even I try to modify this query but unable to do so.. Please help me with the query so that I can add all the respective data in the same query.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. As I already mentioned in my previous comment, you need to update your question with your sample input data and expected output. That should explain it. Furthermore do not say your problem is urgent. If you are still blocked a month later it clearly isn't.